# User Management in Ionic2 with Meteor

Tags: meteor, ionic-framework, ionic2

as far as I know I need to run `Accounts.createUser(...)` and `Meteor.loginWithPassword(...)` to register and login users. Can someone please tell me which packages I need and how to import them correctly?

At the moment I do the import like this:

```
import 'meteor-client-side';
import 'accounts-base-client-side';

declare let Meteor;
declare let Accounts;
```

and get the errors

```
Accounts.createUser is not a function
Meteor.loginWithPassword is not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the necessary packages

```
npm install meteor-client-side --save
npm install accounts-base-client-side --save
npm install accounts-password-client-side --save
```

Import them in `main.dev.ts`/`main.prod.ts` with

```
import 'meteor-client-side';
import 'accounts-base-client-side';
import 'accounts-password-client-side';
```

Then you can declare `Meteor`/`Accounts` everywhere else with

```
declare let Meteor;
declare let Accounts;
```

and use it for example as

```
Accounts.createUser({ username: username, password: password }, (e: Error) => {
  if (e) return this.handleError(e);

  this.navCtrl.setRoot(MyPage, {}, {
    animate: true
  });

});
```

or

```
Meteor.loginWithPassword(username, password, (e: Error) => {
  if (e) return this.handleError(e);

  this.navCtrl.setRoot(MyPage, {}, {
    animate: true
  });

});
```